# Spark Structured Streaming recovering from a query exception

Tags: scala, apache-spark, spark-structured-streaming

**Is it possible to recover automatically from an exception thrown during query execution?**

**Context:** I'm developing a Spark application that reads data from a Kafka topic, processes the data, and outputs to S3. However, after running for a couple of days in production, the spark application faces some network hiccups from S3 that causes an exception to be thrown and stops the application.  It's also worth mentioning that this application runs on Kubernetes using [GCP's Spark k8s Operator](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/spark-on-k8s-operator).

From what I've seen so far, these exceptions are minor and a simple restart of the application solves the issue.  Can we handle those exceptions and restart the structured streaming query automatically?

**Here's an example of a thrown exception:**

```
    Exception in thread "main" org.apache.spark.sql.streaming.StreamingQueryException: Job aborted.
    === Streaming Query ===
    Identifier: ...
    Current Committed Offsets: ...
    Current Available Offsets: ...

    Current State: ACTIVE
    Thread State: RUNNABLE

    Logical Plan: ...

        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.StreamExecution.org$apache$spark$sql$execution$streaming$StreamExecution$$runStream(StreamExecution.scala:297)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.StreamExecution$$anon$1.run(StreamExecution.scala:193)
    Caused by: org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted.
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileFormatWriter$.write(FileFormatWriter.scala:198)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.InsertIntoHadoopFsRelationCommand.run(InsertIntoHadoopFsRelationCommand.scala:159)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.command.DataWritingCommandExec.sideEffectResult$lzycompute(commands.scala:104)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.command.DataWritingCommandExec.sideEffectResult(commands.scala:102)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.command.DataWritingCommandExec.doExecute(commands.scala:122)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$execute$1.apply(SparkPlan.scala:131)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$execute$1.apply(SparkPlan.scala:127)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$executeQuery$1.apply(SparkPlan.scala:155)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:151)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.executeQuery(SparkPlan.scala:152)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.execute(SparkPlan.scala:127)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.toRdd$lzycompute(QueryExecution.scala:80)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.toRdd(QueryExecution.scala:80)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter$$anonfun$runCommand$1.apply(DataFrameWriter.scala:676)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter$$anonfun$runCommand$1.apply(DataFrameWriter.scala:676)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$$anonfun$withNewExecutionId$1.apply(SQLExecution.scala:78)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.withSQLConfPropagated(SQLExecution.scala:125)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.withNewExecutionId(SQLExecution.scala:73)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter.runCommand(DataFrameWriter.scala:676)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter.saveToV1Source(DataFrameWriter.scala:285)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter.save(DataFrameWriter.scala:271)
        at io.blahblahView$$anonfun$11$$anonfun$apply$2.apply(View.scala:90)
        at io.blahblahView $$anonfun$11$$anonfun$apply$2.apply(View.scala:82)
        at scala.collection.TraversableLike$WithFilter$$anonfun$foreach$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:733)
        at scala.collection.IndexedSeqOptimized$class.foreach(IndexedSeqOptimized.scala:33)
        at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayOps$ofRef.foreach(ArrayOps.scala:186)
        at scala.collection.TraversableLike$WithFilter.foreach(TraversableLike.scala:732)
        at io.blahblahView$$anonfun$11.apply(View.scala:82)
        at io.blahblahView$$anonfun$11.apply(View.scala:79)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.sources.ForeachBatchSink.addBatch(ForeachBatchSink.scala:35)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.MicroBatchExecution$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$sql$execution$streaming$MicroBatchExecution$$runBatch$5$$anonfun$apply$17.apply(MicroBatchExecution.scala:537)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$$anonfun$withNewExecutionId$1.apply(SQLExecution.scala:78)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.withSQLConfPropagated(SQLExecution.scala:125)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.withNewExecutionId(SQLExecution.scala:73)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.MicroBatchExecution$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$sql$execution$streaming$MicroBatchExecution$$runBatch$5.apply(MicroBatchExecution.scala:535)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.ProgressReporter$class.reportTimeTaken(ProgressReporter.scala:351)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.StreamExecution.reportTimeTaken(StreamExecution.scala:58)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.MicroBatchExecution.org$apache$spark$sql$execution$streaming$MicroBatchExecution$$runBatch(MicroBatchExecution.scala:534)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.MicroBatchExecution$$anonfun$runActivatedStream$1$$anonfun$apply$mcZ$sp$1.apply$mcV$sp(MicroBatchExecution.scala:198)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.MicroBatchExecution$$anonfun$runActivatedStream$1$$anonfun$apply$mcZ$sp$1.apply(MicroBatchExecution.scala:166)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.MicroBatchExecution$$anonfun$runActivatedStream$1$$anonfun$apply$mcZ$sp$1.apply(MicroBatchExecution.scala:166)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.ProgressReporter$class.reportTimeTaken(ProgressReporter.scala:351)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.StreamExecution.reportTimeTaken(StreamExecution.scala:58)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.MicroBatchExecution$$anonfun$runActivatedStream$1.apply$mcZ$sp(MicroBatchExecution.scala:166)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.ProcessingTimeExecutor.execute(TriggerExecutor.scala:56)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.MicroBatchExecution.runActivatedStream(MicroBatchExecution.scala:160)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.StreamExecution.org$apache$spark$sql$execution$streaming$StreamExecution$$runStream(StreamExecution.scala:281)
        ... 1 more
    Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: No such file or directory: s3a://.../view/v1/_temporary/0
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3a.S3AFileSystem.getFileStatus(S3AFileSystem.java:993)
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3a.S3AFileSystem.listStatus(S3AFileSystem.java:734)
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.listStatus(FileSystem.java:1517)
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.listStatus(FileSystem.java:1557)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.output.FileOutputCommitter.getAllCommittedTaskPaths(FileOutputCommitter.java:291)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.output.FileOutputCommitter.commitJobInternal(FileOutputCommitter.java:361)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.output.FileOutputCommitter.commitJob(FileOutputCommitter.java:334)
        at org.apache.parquet.hadoop.ParquetOutputCommitter.commitJob(ParquetOutputCommitter.java:48)
        at org.apache.spark.internal.io.HadoopMapReduceCommitProtocol.commitJob(HadoopMapReduceCommitProtocol.scala:166)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileFormatWriter$.write(FileFormatWriter.scala:187)
        ... 47 more
```

**What's the simplest way of taking care of such issues automatically?**

Comment: There is not. There is also nothing in the manuals from Databricks, only the stuff on node recovery & checkpointing for workers etc. If the driver fails it is also over.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

After spending too many hours trying to find an elegant fix to this issue, and not finding anything, here's what I came up with.

Some might say it's a hack, but it's simple, it works and solves a complex problem. I tested it in production and it solves the issue of recovering automatically from failure due to an occasional minor exception.

I call it a **The Query Watchdog**. Here's the simplest version where the watchdog will retry running the query indefinitely:

```
val writer = df.writeStream...

while (true) {
   val query = writer.start()

   try {
        query.awaitTermination()
   } 
   catch {
       case e: StreamingQueryException => println("Streaming Query Exception caught!: " + e);
   }
}
```

Some people might want to replace the `while(true)` with some kind of counter to limit the number of retries. Someone could also supplement this code and send notifications through slack or email whenever a retry happened. Others could simply collect the number of retries in Prometheus.

Hope it helps,

Cheers

Comment: an occasional minor exception means?

Comment: I am not convinced to be honest.

Comment: By occasional minor exception, I mean errors that disappear upon restarting the query, eg. network hiccups like temporary 404's from S3.

Comment: so, why is it not in the databricks guide?

Comment: Good question. I'm going to assume that they don't want to recommend workarounds in their official documentation.

Comment: @OneCricketeer   Can I ask for your considered opinion here pls?Is this indeed so? Why is it not in the manuals?

Comment: This looks convincing, will try this option and update here the status. Thanks Jeremie

Answer (score 0):

No, there is not in a reliable way to do this. BTW, No is also an answer.

- Logic for checking exceptions are generally via try / catch running on the driver.
- As unexpected situations at Executor level are already standardly handled by the Spark Framework itself for Structured Streaming, and if the error is non-recoverable, then the App / Job simply crashes after signalling of error(s) back to the driver unless you code try / catch within the various foreachXXX constructs.

  - That said, it is not clear for the foreachXXX constructs that the micro batch will be recoverable in such an approach afaics, some part of the microbatch is highly likely lost. Hard to test though.
- Given that Spark has things standardly catered for that you cannot hook into, why would it be possible to insert a loop or try/catch in the source of the program? Likewise broadcast variables area an issue - although some have techniques around this so they say. But it is not in the spirit of the framework.

So, good question as I wonder(ed) about this (in the past).

Answer (score 0):

Depending on you Spark runtime and environment, an alternative recommended for example in [Databricks documentation](https://docs.databricks.com/structured-streaming/query-recovery.html) is to simply let the streaming queries fail so that the retries can be handled at Spark job level.

One of the benefits of this is that it decouples the retry policy and related email notifications from your application.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using the Spark Operator, why not using its restart functionality? If the controller notices that the application has stopped then it will re-submit it automatically.

This will work assuming that the application fails, i.e. the driver pod stops. There are some cases where a driver exception is thrown but the driver pod keeps running without doing anything. In that case the Spark Operator will think that the application is still running ok.